# webpack5 how to use assts module with custom loader?

Tags: webpack-5

i write down a custom loader to record the orginal image file's info, eg. file update time.
and then set a `date-updatetime` property on the `img` node.

so basicly i should use asset module in webpack5 with a custom loader

this is the current loader's code:

`setMediaFileInfoLoader.js`

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const loaderUtils = require('loader-utils');

module.exports = function(source,srouceMap) {
  const callback = this.async();
  const resourcePath = this.resourcePath;
  const filename= path.relative(this.rootContext,resourcePath)

  let ext=path.extname(filename);
  let name=path.basename(filename,ext);

  //只有图片或者视频才会有文件信息
  //only handle media files
    if (!/\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp|mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac|mov|wmv|avi|flv|mkv|ts|mpd|m3u8)$/i.test(ext)) {  
        callback(null, source);
        return;
    }

    if(!this._module.generator.filename)
    {
        callback(null, source);
        return;
    }

  fs.stat(resourcePath, (err, stats) => {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
      return;
    }

    const updateTime = stats.mtime.getTime();
    const fileSize = stats.size;
    let outputFileName=this._module.generator.filename({ filename }).replace(/\[name\]/g, name).replace(/\[ext\]/g, ext);
    
    // this.emitFile(outputFileName, source,srouceMap,{
    //     updateTime,
    //     fileSize
    //   });

    // Store the file info in the loader context
    this._compilation.__fileInfos = this._compilation.__fileInfos || {};
    this._compilation.__fileInfos[outputFileName] = {
      updateTime,
      fileSize
    };

    callback(null, source);
    
  });
};
```

then in plugin, i try to force load the media file via custom loader, code like this
`AddMediaFileInfoPlugin.js`

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

class AddMediaFileInfoPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {

    compiler.hooks.normalModuleFactory.tap('AddMediaFileInfoPlugin', (factory) => {
        factory.hooks.beforeResolve.tap('AddMediaFileInfoPlugin', (data) => {
          if (/\.png|svg|gif|jpe?g|mov|mp4?$/i.test(data.request)) {
            data.request = path.resolve(__dirname, 'setMediaFileInfoLoader') + '!' + data.request;
          }
          return undefined; // Do not return anything
        });
      });


    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('AddMediaFileInfoPlugin', (compilation) => {
      HtmlWebpackPlugin.getHooks(compilation).beforeEmit.tapAsync(
        'AddMediaFileInfoPlugin',
        (data, cb) => {
          const $ = cheerio.load(data.html);
          $('img, video').each((index, element) => {
            const src = $(element).attr('src');
            const assetName=src?.slice(1);
            // const assetInfo=compilation.assetsInfo.get(assetName);
            const asset = compilation.assets[assetName];
            if (asset) {

                const fileInfo = compilation.__fileInfos?.[assetName];
                if (fileInfo) {

                  $(element).attr('data-updatetime', fileInfo.updateTime);
                  $(element).attr('data-filesize', fileInfo.fileSize);

                }

            }
          });
          data.html = $.html();
          cb(null, data);
        }
      );
    });
  }
}

module.exports = AddMediaFileInfoPlugin;
```

some code in my webpack.config.js is like this

```
 {
          test: /\.(png|svg|gif|jpe?g)$/,          
          type:'asset',
          generator: {
            filename: (pathData) => {
              const filepath = path
                .dirname(pathData.filename)
                .split("/")
                .slice(3)
                .join("_");
              return `files/${filepath}_[name][ext]`;
            },
          },
          parser: {
            dataUrlCondition: {
              maxSize: 10 * 1024
            }
          }
        },
...
 plugins: [
    new AddMediaFileInfoPlugin()
  ]
```

after compile, i can see the html code like this

```
<img src="/files/pic1.jpg" data-updatetime="1707276411445" data-filesize="950772">
```

however, it looks the picture is not emit correctly, i can not see the picture in webpage.

how to make it all works fine?